# Android Data Binding. Button onClick not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I am stuck here, help.

I've got the following code:

ProfileFragment:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
        private val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel by viewModels()
    
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            binding.viewModel = profileViewModel
            binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    
            return binding.root
        }
    }
```

ProfileViewModel:

```
class ProfileViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
) : ViewModel() {

   fun getUser() {
     ....
   } 
}
```

fragment_profile.xml:

```
 <data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="my.app.viewmodel.ProfileViewModel" />

</data>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.getUser()}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the `onClick` is never triggered no matter what I do and how I try.
However, as soon as I do it like this in `ProfileFragment` it works just fine:

```
binding.myButton.setOnClickListener {
   profileViewModel.getUser()
}
```

Any ideas? Cause I am stuck here

Comment: I think your issue relies with this line: `private val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel by viewModels()`. since you've parameterized constructor for view model, fragment is not able to retain that instance for you because you might not be providing `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to it. Not sure about your underlying DI.

Comment: @JeelVankhede unfortunately, what you had described is not related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this issue still exist or not
but if you are using data binding and hilt for dependency injection please add below lines in your fragment onViewCreated

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.viewModel = profileViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this problem for me was adding the fragment reference to itself in *onCreateView*:

```
binding.<fragment_name> = this
```

Like so:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreateView")
        binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)        
        binding.settingsFragment = this  <---
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return binding.root
}
```